# An integral with density function of $N(\hat{a}, \frac{1}{s})$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, normal-distribution

I am stucked on this integral, which is from a research paper in Finance, for a while, so can anyone please help walk me through how we can get the answer on the RHS of this integral?

Prove: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \max\ (0,\frac{t\hat{a}+sy}{t+s})\sqrt{\frac{H}{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{H}{2}(y-\hat{a})^{2}}dy= \hat{a}\ N[-(\frac{-t\hat{a}}{s}-\hat{a})\sqrt{H}] +\frac{\sqrt{H}}{t}\phi [(\frac{-t\hat{a}}{s}-\hat{a})\sqrt{H}]$

where N is distribution function of standard normal random variable, $\phi$ is its corresponding density function, and y follows normal distribution $N(\hat{a}, \frac{1}{s})$.

I also can't see how from the equation above, the author came up with these partial derivatives, given $H=\frac{st}{s+t}$:

$\frac{\partial\ V}{\partial\hat{a}} = N + \hat{a}\phi\sqrt{H} + \frac{H}{t}(\frac{-t\hat{a}}{s}-\hat{a})\phi\sqrt{H}$ = N, $\ \frac{\partial\ V}{\partial\frac{t\hat{a}}{s}}=0$

$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = (-1+\frac{s}{2s+2t})(\frac{\sqrt{H}}{t^2})\phi$, $\frac{\partial V}{\partial s} = \frac{t}{2(t+s)^2\sqrt{H}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For $\beta>0$, we have: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \max(0,\alpha+\beta x)\phi(x)\,dx = \int_{-\alpha/\beta}^\infty (\alpha+\beta x)\phi(x)\,dx =\alpha N(\alpha/\beta) + \beta\phi(\alpha/\beta), $$
by using 
$$ \int \phi(x)dx = N(x) +C, \; \int x\phi(x)dx = -\phi(x) +C. $$

To use it in your calculation apply change of variable $x = \sqrt{H}(y-\hat{a})$.

**Edit:** It seems to me that original random variable should have been ${\rm Normal}(\hat{a}, 1/H)$ (not ${\rm Normal}(\hat{a}, 1/s)$).

**Edit2:** Denoting by $V(\alpha, \beta):= \alpha N(\alpha/\beta) + \beta\phi(\alpha/\beta)$, we get
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial \alpha} = N(\alpha/\beta)+ \alpha/\beta N'(\alpha/\beta) +\phi'(\alpha/\beta) $$
$$ =  N(\alpha/\beta)+ \alpha/\beta \phi(\alpha/\beta) -\alpha/\beta\phi(\alpha/\beta) $$
$$ =  N(\alpha/\beta).$$

**Edit3:** $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\max\left(0,\frac{t\hat{a}+sy}{t+s}\right)\sqrt{\frac{H}{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{H}{2}(y-\hat{a})^{2}}dy$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\max \left(0,\frac{t\hat{a}+s\left(x/\sqrt{H}+\hat{a}\right)}{t+s}\right)\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}dx $$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\max \left(0,\hat{a}+\frac{s}{\sqrt{H}(t+s)}x \right)\phi(x) dx $$ 
We now take 
$$\alpha = \hat{a}$$
and
$$ \beta = \frac{s}{\sqrt{H}(t+s)}, \quad \frac{\alpha}{\beta} = \left(\hat{a}+\frac{t\hat{a}}{s}\right)\sqrt{H}. $$
Using the formula above, we get:
$$ \hat{a} N\left(\left(\hat{a}+\frac{t\hat{a}}{s}\right)\sqrt{H}\right) + \frac{s}{\sqrt{H}(t+s)}\phi\left(\left(\hat{a}+\frac{t\hat{a}}{s}\right)\sqrt{H}\right)$$
 Using $H:=st/(s+t)$ (hence $ \beta = \sqrt{H}/t$) as in the source paper, we have further:
$$ V(\hat{a},s,t):=\hat{a} N\left(\left(\hat{a}+\frac{t\hat{a}}{s}\right)\sqrt{H}\right) + \frac{\sqrt{H}}{t}\phi\left(\left(\hat{a}+\frac{t\hat{a}}{s}\right)\sqrt{H}\right) $$

**Edit4** Similar to Edit2:
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial\hat{a}}=  N\left(\left(\hat{a}+\frac{t\hat{a}}{s}\right)\sqrt{H}\right).
$$

**Edit5** Introducing variable $Y:=\hat{a}t/s$, we have
$$  V= \hat{a} N\left(\left(\hat{a}+Y\right)\sqrt{H}\right) + \frac{\sqrt{H}}{t}\phi\left(\left(\hat{a}+Y\right)\sqrt{H}\right). $$
So:
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial Y} = \hat{a} \phi\left(\left(\hat{a}+Y\right)\sqrt{H}\right) \sqrt{H}
-\frac{\sqrt{H}}{t}\left(\hat{a}+Y\right)\sqrt{H}\phi\left(\left(\hat{a}+Y\right)\sqrt{H}\right)\sqrt{H} = 0,$$
due to observation (using definition of $Y$ and $H$):
$$ \frac{\sqrt{H}}{t}\left(\hat{a}+Y\right)\sqrt{H} = \hat{a}.$$

**Edit6** Noting that:

$$V= \hat{a} N\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right) + \frac{\sqrt{H}}{t}\phi\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right),$$

we get:

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial s} =\hat{a} \phi\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right) \left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right)'_s +\left( \frac{\sqrt{H}}{t}\right)'_s\phi\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right) $$
$$ - \frac{\sqrt{H}}{t} \frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}} \phi\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right)\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right)'_s$$
$$ = \left( \frac{\sqrt{H}}{t}\right)'_s\phi\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right)=\frac{H'_s}{2t\sqrt{H}} \phi\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right)= \frac{t}{2(t+s)^2\sqrt{H}}\phi\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right)$$

**Edit7:** Same calculation sequence gives:

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = \left( \frac{\sqrt{H}}{t}\right)'_t\phi\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right)=\frac{\frac{H'_t}{2\sqrt{H}}t-\sqrt{H}}{t^2}\phi\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right)$$
$$ = \left(\frac{H'_t}{2{H}}t -1\right) \frac{\sqrt{H}}{t^2}\phi\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right)=\left( \frac{s}{2(s+t)}-1\right) \frac{\sqrt{H}}{t^2}\phi\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. May you elaborate on how did you get the two integrals, and how the two integrals become when $x\rightarrow \infty$? And do you see how we can end up with the two partial derivatives above from the equation?

Comment: Btw, even after using your two integrals and the suggested change of variables, I don't see how the coefficients $\frac{1}{t+s}$ and $\frac{s}{t+s}$ became $\hat{a}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{H}}{t}$, respectively.

Comment: $N'(x)=\phi(x)$ and $\phi'(x)=-x\phi(x)$ by their definitions as functions, and $\phi(x)$ goes to $0$ when $x$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: I added Edit2 as an example of manipulation of derivatives with respect to parameters.

Comment: many thanks for your quick reply regards to the partial derivatives!! But then I still can't see how $\frac{\partial V}{\partial\beta} = 0$, and how the formula $\frac{\partial V}{\partial\hat{a}}$  gives $\phi$ which doesn't have any arguments? Can you please help elaborate on the proof for the integral regards to my 1st and 2nd posts above?

Comment: Because $\phi$ is a function, so that's why I don't see how $\phi$ can stay alone?

Comment: can you be more specific about the $\frac{\partial V}{\partial a}$? I only got the following: $N$+ $\hat{a} (\frac{t}{s}+1)\sqrt{H}\phi + \frac{H}{t}\times (\frac{t\hat{a}}{s}-\hat{a})(\frac{t}{s}+1)\phi$, but this is not equal to the author's result given above. I can't see where did I do wrong with this derivatives though:(

Comment: I can see that the only way to obtain the author's answer for the partial derivative of $V$ w.r.t $\hat{a}$ is fixing the term $\frac{t\hat{a}}{c}$, and the derivative only works with the remaining term $-\hat{a}$. In his paper, he let the term $\frac{t\hat{a}}{c}=Y_c$, but then he didn't mention anything about fixing this $Y_c$ when taking the derivative, except he mentioned $\frac{\partial V}{\partial Y_c}=0$. I think this implies V is the 2-variable function in terms of $Y_c$ and $\hat{a}$? But I don't see how he can treat these 2 variables as independent to take the derivatives?

Comment: I added Edit3 trying to get their formula. But I failed. Feel free to edit my text in the answer. Just make sure that the starting point is really $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\max\left(0,\frac{t\hat{a}+sy}{t+s}\right)\sqrt{\frac{H}{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{H}{2}(y-\hat{a})^{2}}dy$

Comment: Once we agree on the correct formula, I'll try the derivative with respect to $\hat{a}$ too. The other derivative doesn't make much sense without assumptions that you mentioned. And $\phi$ is never by itself. It needs to be applied to something, $\phi(\ldots)$, at all times.

Comment: Btw, all the formulas above, and their brief proofs (pages 102 + 113) are in this paper: http://fisher.osu.edu/supplements/10/10821/hwaer98.pdf

Comment: can you also help check why on page 113, $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}=(-1+\frac{s}{2(s+t)})\frac{\sqrt{H}}{t^2}\phi$? Again, I only got this one equal to $\frac{-\sqrt{H}}{t^2}\phi$, but the final result still holds.

Comment: I also checked the equation on page 113: $\frac{\partial V}{\partial s}=\frac{t}{2(t+s)^2\sqrt{H}}\phi$, and I got $\frac{\partial V}{\partial s} = \frac{-2\hat{a}^{2}t}{s^2}\sqrt{H}\phi$ So weird:(

Comment: your formula is correct, since I should have said $H=\frac{st}{s+t}$. Great work! Hopefully you can help me work out the two partial derivatives mentioned in the two posts right above, cause I couldn't get what the author got:(

Comment: I think I got how he arrived at the results for the partial derivatives in my original post. In fact, the 2nd partial derivative is proved by using the last 2 terms in the proof of the first partial derivative. However, I still can't get the correct results for $\frac{\partial V}{\partial s}$ and  $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$

Comment: did you have a chance to read my latest comments above? Please help me if you can, since I really want to find out where I got wrong with the two partial derivatives.

Comment: Not yet. The first two derivatives in $\hat{a}$ and $Y$ make sense. The definition of $H$ helped. The derivatives in $s$ and $t$ they got don't even have $\hat{a}$ in them. I hope $\hat{a}$ is not also a function of $s$ and/or $t$, is it?

Comment: Using the last observation in Edit5, what you have now is:$V= \hat{a} N\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right) + \frac{\sqrt{H}}{t}\phi\left(\frac{\hat{a}t}{\sqrt{H}}\right)$

Comment: And note that $H^{\prime}_s = t^2/(t+s)^2$ and $H_t^{\prime}=s^2/(t+s)^2$.

Comment: And of course, relations $N'(x)=\phi(x)$ and $\phi'(x)=-x\phi(x)$. I cant think of anything else.

Comment: @user177196 It works! Have a look at Edit6.

Comment: Excellent work for $\frac{\partial V}{\partial s}$!!Many thanks for your help. Just a minor comment: I believe you forgot the $\phi$ term in the last two equalities. Did you try the last one, $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$?

Comment: Yes, same calculation sequence gives it (Edit7).

Comment: I also got the same for that derivative! Many thanks for your great help, ir7:) Merry Xmas and Happy New Year to you and your family!!

Comment: Merry Xmas to you too!